# LaTeX preview on HiDPI display

Tags: latex, preview-latex

LaTeX preview with `C-c C-x C-l` looks very tiny on my HiDPI screen. What can I do to solve this?[image]

Answer (score 5):

The variable `preview-scale-function` in the `preview-appearance` group controls this. From the customization menu:

> Preview Scale Function: [Value Menu] preview-scale-from-face
>   Calculate preview scale from ‘preview-reference-face’.
>   This calculates the scale of EPS images from a document assumed
>   to have a default font size given by function ‘preview-document-pt’
>   so that they match the reference face in height.
>
> Scale factor for included previews.
>   This can be either a function to calculate the scale, or a fixed number.

Try setting the value to various fixed numbers. The preview sizes should shift up or down accordingly.

Comment: strange, tried to look it up on customize but it says there's nothing matching it...

Comment: It won't show up in customise until after preview-latex is loaded. You might have to open a .Tex file or make a preview first, then customize-variable

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the rendered LaTeX equations scaled

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(setq org-format-latex-options (plist-put org-format-latex-options :scale 1.4))
#+END_SRC
```

The scale 1.4 is Ok in my setup... try it, and change the number to fit your needs.

Comment: I think the question was asking about LaTeX files, not LaTeX blocks in org files.